# rails namespace uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm making admin panel in my app, I made the scaffold user controller for admin (User Model already exists) like this:

```
rails g scaffold_controller Admin::User username:string password_digest:string role:string
```

and in routes

```
namespace :admin do
resources :users
resources :dashboard
end
```

and controllers/admin/users_controllers.erb looks like

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /admin/users
  # GET /admin/users.json
  def index
    @admin_users = Admin::User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @admin_users }
    end
  end
```

so when i go to url /admin/users i got the following error:

```
NameError in Admin::UsersController#index

uninitialized constant Admin::User
```

How do i solve this problem

Thanks

Comment: How does `app/models/admin/user.rb` look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your preexisting `User` model isn't namespaced, try replacing

```
@admin_users = Admin::User.all
```

with

```
@admin_users = ::User.all
```

Comment: @admin_users = ::User.all gives routes error: undefined method `user_path'

Comment: Code generated by scaffold expects your `User` model to be in module `Admin`, just like the controller. Make sure your `routes.rb` has something like `namespace :admin { resources :users }`; then go to your `app/views/admin/users/index.html.erb` and change `link_to 'Show', admin_user` to `link_to 'Show', admin_user_path(admin_user)`; and `link_to 'Destroy', admin_user, ...` to `link_to 'Destroy', admin_user_path(admin_user), ...`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the generator doesn't created the directory models/admin so you should call User.all and not Admin::User.all.

Check if the user.rb is in models or models/admin...

Comment: there's no directory models/admin... do i have to create separate models for admin namespace, Also User.all gives routes error "undefined method `user_path'"

Comment: If you want yes... but it is not necessary. I think in your case you don't want that. The user should be in the directory models, and then you'll always call for User.all.

Comment: gives routes error "undefined method `user_path'" this is because you don't have a users_controller but instead a admin_users_controller, so  you have admin_users_path and not an users_path... and in the route you have a namespace :admin do resources :users and not a resources :users outside namespace admin

Answer (score 2):

In my particular case, I had named the files and classes correctly but the containing **folder** was named **incorrectly**.

I had:

```
/models/maps/type.rb
```

I had to change it to:

```
/models/map/type.rb
```

Notice the singular folder name. Changing it to singular allowed Rails to automatically load the right class and no longer have this error at runtime.